# React useEffect not updating when switching between pages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state, use-effect

I have two states (userCustomers and loans) which are depending on a state coming from a custom hook (customers).

```js
  const [customers] = useLoanCustomers(state.contents.date)
  const [userCustomers, setUserCustomers] = useState<DwCustomerHeadline[]>([])
  const [loans, setLoans] = useState<DwLoanContract[]>([])
```

So I filter data depending on the output of the useLoanCustomers and have an empty array as initial state.
When I refresh the page, the useEffect works fine and sets the states of "userCustomers" and "loans"

But when I switch between pages/routes, the useEffect does not work and keeps the initial state [].
e.g this component is on 'http://localhost:3000/user/overview'.
if I go to another route like 'http://localhost:3000/clients' and then back to '/user/overview', the states "userCustomers" and "loans" are empty. So the useEffect does not set those states.
"useLoanCustomers" is loading as expected and holds all the data.

when I console log inside the useEffect, I can see that useEffect is running properly depending on the dependency change.
But it is not setting the other two states. As said, only when I refresh the page.

Has anyone a clue what's wrong, because I've already tried so much but can't figure it out.

This is my entire component

```js
export const Overview: React.FC<OverviewProps> = ({ user }) => {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak()
  const { state } = useContext(DashboardContext)
  const [customers] = useLoanCustomers(state.contents.date)
  const [userCustomers, setUserCustomers] = useState<DwCustomerHeadline[]>([])
  const [loans, setLoans] = useState<DwLoanContract[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredCustomers = customers.filter((customer) => customer.stafferEmail === user?.email)
    setUserCustomers(filteredCustomers)

    Promise.all(filteredCustomers.map((customer) => getCustomerLoans(keycloak, customer.counterpartyId))).then((res) =>
      setLoans(res.flat())
    )
  }, [customers])

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid gap-4 p-2 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-1">
        <div className="col-span-2 shadow-sm">
          <KeyMetrics />
        </div>
        <div className="shadow-sm">
          <NextReview customers={userCustomers} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid gap-4 p-2 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-1 grid-rows-2">
        <div className="md:h-80 col-span-2 shadow-sm">
          <ErpOverview customers={userCustomers} />
        </div>
        <div className="row-span-2 shadow-sm" style={{ height: '34rem' }}>
          <Outflow loans={loans} endDate={state.contents.date} />
        </div>
        <div className="h-52 col-span-2 shadow-sm">
          <LoanArrears customers={userCustomers} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: you have multiple `promises` inside `useEffect` but your code did not _await_ them. I think that causes the problem.

Comment: But even the 'setUserCustomers(filteredCustomers)', which does not have a promise, does not work and is not updating userCustomers. only on page refresh.

Comment: You may need to return a cleanup function from `useEffect`, see [Example Using Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1). This is called when the component is destroyed.

Comment: the `setState` method is asynchronous also

Comment: @BraveVN there's no logical difference between using `await` and `then` on the promises.

Comment: I already tried with clean up function, but it didn't work. or maybe I did something wrong. But I tried now to changed from custom hook 'useLoanCustomers(state.contents.date)' to a normal promise and there it works now. 
So one useEffect to get the customers with dependency [], and a second useEffect to filter on that with dependency [customers]
So something does not like to refer to the custom hook state, I don't know. If anyone knows, still appreciate if anyone can tell. but for now I fixed it with not using the custom hook.